# React app not rendering for internet explorer

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My react app is not working on Internet explorer 11. It is working fine on firefox, safari and chrome.

This is my package.json file below

```
{
  "name": "amplifyapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fanky.
it's because you use the browserlist settings.

please read this [document](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) carefully.
if you run your project in production mode, your app properly work fine.

check these settings on this [site](https://browserl.ist/).

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Dragon White, i will check it out right now!